# Categorical vs quantitative data

Tags: categorical-data, t-test, chi-squared-test

So this is a super simple question. I have a project for which I am comparing the number of seed in expensive apples vs the number of seeds in cheaper apples. I was thinking that number of seeds is a categorical variable I would need to use a chi-square test to determine significance. Is this correct? Or would I be able to use a T-test to test for significance between the mean number of seeds in expensive apples vs the mean in cheaper ones.

Answer (score 1):

Number of seeds is a count variable. The t-test should be fine, because taking the mean of the number of seeds makes sense.

If you want to make a more complex model (e.g. by including other characteristics of the apples) then you probably want some form of count regression model like Poisson regression or  negative binomial regression.